# How to limit access to pages with some conditions?

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, locale

I have two languages available on my website (English / Korean) using locale. But, some of the pages are not available Korean language so I want to temporarily hide the pages ( Blog, Podcast, FAQ).

In index.html, I put a condition `-if I18n.locale == :en` above links that I want to hide. But, the problem is visitors still able to access those pages with Korean.

Visitors can go to the blog page with English and change language from there or they can type URL.(/kr/blog)

Can I get advice on how to prevent this?

I ultimately want visitors to be redirected landing page if they are on blog page and click Korean.

Comment: Unless this a legacy app why Rails 4.x?

Comment: You can put a condition in the respective action of the controller and redirect it to another page.

Answer (score 4):

In your controller, you can redirect conditionally:

```
unless I18n.locale == "en"
  redirect_to :the_other_page
end
```